# Filtering a list lookup in Nintex Forms using an inline function

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2010, filtering, nintex-workflow

I am building a list form for SharePoint 2010 using Nintex Forms 2010.

The user must select an item from a different list, so I have added a List Lookup control. But the user can only select among items that starts with a specific string.

For example, the lookup list could contain items with titles 'foo1','foo2','bar1','bar2'. I only want the user to be able to select 'foo1' or 'foo2'.

In the filtering section of the List Lookup control I have specified the following:

- Filter available selections = By a specific value
- Where field = fn-Substring("Title",0,3)
- Filtered by value = foo

Unfortunately this does not result in any options for the user to select - just an empty control.

If I change the filter to:

- Where feild = Title
- Filtered by value = foo1

Then I get the foo1 option - and only that one. Trying something like

- Filtered by value = foo*

does not work either.

So how should I define the filter to get it to work. Or is what I am trying not possible in Nintex Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline function won't work in your case, because it is a client side function, and your parameter is a server side object.

There two alternative ways can help with your request in server side.

1.Add a calculated value column to your list, use LEFT function to cut the search key for yourself:`LEFT([Title],3)`. In nintex form, you can use this column to filter the list items.

2. Filter the list items in a view instead of nintex form. Suppose you have already known the [source view] property in List Lookup control.